# MongoDB relationship management

Tags: mongodb

I have a question , I have two collections , Users and roles and I hold the role of the user 's own document (SystemRoles property).
if an update on the role definitions then how to update a user 's role information or have I manage more professional to solve this problem ?

Example User  Document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55606cf9a6df191510963a3b"),
    "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-05-23T12:05:13.110Z"),
    "IsActive" : true,
    "Provider" : null,
    "FirstName" : "admin",
    "LastName" : "admin",
    "BirthDay" : ISODate("1984-08-18T21:00:00.000Z"),
    "Gender" : null,
    "ImageUrl" : "~/Images/avatar.png",
    "ActorId" : ObjectId("55606cf9a6df191510963a39"),
    "DepartmentName" : "Ana Kurum",
    "DepartmentId" : ObjectId("55606cf9a6df191510963a38"),
    "SystemRoles" : [ 
        {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55643948a6df1915a88717a4"),
        "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-05-26T09:13:44.287Z"),
        "IsActive" : true,
        "Name" : "Administrator",
        "Path" : "\\",
        "TypeId" : 3,
        "ParentActorId" : null
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55643948a6df1915a88717a5"),
        "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-05-26T09:13:44.392Z"),
        "IsActive" : true,
        "Name" : "User",
        "Path" : "\\",
        "TypeId" : 3,
        "ParentActorId" : null
    }
    ],
```

Comment: Mongo is schemaless. There is no connection between 2 collections. You have to update both collections

Comment: Ok. The second question : So if you want to browse as paging the user's role What should I do then.

Comment: Actually, there are many ways to manage the situation. You can hold the role id in the SystemRoles array... and fetch the role data as required

Comment: I was holding role id before, but i did not get the definition of a role by sending the user id with a single query. i am new user for mongodb , forgive my question :)

Comment: you need 2 queries...

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb doesn't provide any support for relationship between multiple collections. It is different from the sql approach of databases. No-sql supports logical relationship which is maintained by the schema design itself. The basic goal of it is to reduce dependency on parts of documents and speedup the process.

```
"address": [
      {
         "building": "22 A, Indiana Apt",
         "pincode": 123456,
         "city": "Los Angeles",
         "state": "California"
      },
      {
         "building": "170 A, Acropolis Apt",
         "pincode": 456789,
         "city": "Chicago",
         "state": "Illinois"
      }]
```

For demo example you could visit [mongodb-useful-basics](http://www.tinytute.com/mongodb-useful-basics/)